# Mongoose Order Populars By Total Rating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to get popular products from MongoDB. Here is my schema;

```js
  ...
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  rating: [{
    user : {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'users'
    },
    rate: {
      type: Number,
      min: 1,
      max: 5
    }
  }],
  created_at : {
    type : Date
  },
  ...
```

I want to order by `rating.rate` sum. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you have user both in the top level and in the rating array? What's the point of top level user? Also where is the reference to the product schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution:

```js
db.collection('products').aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$rating"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      sum: {
        "$sum": "$rating.rate"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "sum": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).